# use rank from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, select

how could i implement rank function for example if user has  rank '1' he has admin privileges if  he has '0' he is normal user

i know i have to use something like

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  from users 
 WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' 
   AND password LIKE '{$password}'  
 LIMIT 1";
```

but don't sure how to use it properly

my database looks like

```
username password rank
tom      tom1     0
john     john1    1
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SRC Centr</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center>SRC Centr</h1>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<!-- The HTML login form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        <center>Username: <input type="text" name="username" required /><br /><center>
        <center>Password: <input type="password" name="password" required /><br /><center>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
<?php
} else {
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $rank = $_POST['rank'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}'  LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "<center><h3>Incorrect login</h3></center>";
    } else {
        if ( $rank == "0"){
    header("location: app.php");
 }
else if ( $rank == "1"){
header("location: index.php");
}





}
}
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

thanks :)

Comment: Fix your MySQL injection issues, or anyone who wants to be an admin will be. Further, don't store plaintext passwords.

Comment: You're not getting `$_POST['rank']` from anywhere. Select it from the database rather than get it over POST. And you really ought to hash your passwords, and not to mention SQL vulnerabilities here.

Comment: can you give some sort of example how could i do that?

Comment: You already select everything. Fetch it, `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` and get the rank from there, not from the POST `$rank = $row['rank'];` and check against that. And look into [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for storing passwords more securely, and [`$mysqli->prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to guard yourself against SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, but i keep getting Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null

Comment: `if ( $rank == "0")` your logic is off. You're checking against a POST where as it should be inside a loop. Unless 0 is equal to no value in input. No idea what you want to do here.

Comment: @pregot Where did you place that? It needs to be after `$result = $mysqli->query($sql);`

Comment: Thank you, it is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
if((SELECT rank FROM users WHERE username = {username} and password = {password}) == 1) {
    set rank of user to admin
}
```

Is this what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want, but you could try this

```
$sql ="SELECT username, rank from users 
        WHERE 
           username ='".$_post["username"]."' AND 
           password ='".$_post["password"]."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if( $result == 1) {
    if($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        if($user["rank"] == 1){
            #Do something
        } else {
            #DO somthing
        }
    }
} else { 
    die ("Error");
}
```

Let me know if you need another thing